# TryParse a String Number to DateTime return True

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

This line of code returns `true` and `time` is equal to `"01/02/2016"`:

```
DateTime time;
bool result = DateTime.TryParse("1,2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out time);
```

What can I do to return `false`?

I don't use `DateTime.TryParseExact` because I would have to specify a format like `"YY/MM/DD"`, but I need to use the default format on the PC.

Comment: `How can I do that TryParse method returns False?` -- Give it an invalid string to parse.

Comment: I guess OP wants to return `False` for the specific string `"1,2"`

Comment: How could that be returning `true`?

Comment: "This method tries to ignore unrecognized data, if possible, and fills in missing month, day, and year information with the current date". See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Use [`TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, then.

Answer (score 3):

For what you're trying to do, you're probably better off using [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx).  Instead of making arbitrary assumptions about the string you're parsing, it will return `false` unless the string matches exactly the pattern you want.

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx), you should be able to specify a culture, and ["d" as the format string indicating a "short date"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#ShortDate).  `TryParseExact` should follow suit and use the formatting specified in the culture you provided for short dates.

Comment: This won't really let him use the current culture properly - for example, if the user expects the Month to come first vs. the day...  Specifying a format string will override that, no?

Comment: Yes, it will.  I just assumed that "month first" or "day first" was part of the culture assignment.  I wouldn't expect that to differ from the norm unless the wrong culture was chosen.

Comment: The OP made it clear he didn't want to specify a format though.

Comment: But there is no `DateTime.TryParseMethod` which doesn't need a custom format string.

Comment: Then why the hell does it ask for an `IFormatProvider` then?  I've removed that from my answer.

Comment: It'll work if you specif a "standard format string" - such as "d", which might work for the OP.  Robert, I agree it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with a standard date format, you should go for `DateTime.TryParseExact` with one of those qualifiers (in your case, there's a chance `"d"` might work).  Otherwise, you'll need a custom function around `DateTime.TryParse`.

`DateTime.TryParse` will try to be helpful by ignoring some missing data and filling in some missing data where it can (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)).  If you want to parse it using the current culture, but you still want to exclude certain strings that TryParse would take as valid, you should exclude them before running try parse.  For example

```
public bool MyTryParse(string dateString, out DateTime dt)
{
    dt = new DateTime();
    if (dateString == null)
        return false;


    if (dateString.Length > 3)
            return false;

    return DateTime.TryParse(dateString, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);            
}
```

You can add any additional special case tests you want.  Note that `TryParseExact` is likely not what you want here, **unless you can use a standard date format** as the specified format string (any custom one  will override what the `CurrentCulture` might dictate); compare for example the output of the following:

```
DateTime dt;
bool res = DateTime.TryParseExact("02/03/2001", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
// will output Feb 3, 2001, but a user in GB would probably intend Mar 3, 2001

bool res = DateTime.TryParseExact("02/03/2001", "d", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
// will output Mar 3, 2001, but might be too restrictive for what you want?
res = DateTime.TryParse("02/03/2001", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
// will output Mar 2, 2001, but goes back to your original problem
```

Comment: Hi thanks for all the answers i finally use the way that Dan Field suggest me, and it works, I use it that way, becouse i have to be really specific to use the TryParseExact method, and i want a little more freedom for users.